# IP Tunneling problems with RDP

Tags: linux, windows, networking, rdp, tunneling

I have a problem with IP tunneling.

**Servers** :

- services01 (proxmox host) (internal ips : 10.21.21.0/24) (tunnel ip 172.16.0.1)
- backup01 (proxmox host) (internal ips : 10.21.23.0/24) (tunnel ip 172.16.0.2)

**VMs :**

- 10.21.21.7 - VM1 on services01
- 10.21.23.4 - VM2 on backup01

**Problem :**

- **Scenario 1.** Using KVM login from to VM2 from backup01. Connect to fileshare on 10.21.21.7 and download any ~ 10 GB file, test network functionality, etc - everything is fine, no network problems, speed ~ 1 gbit, no timeouts.
- **Scenario 2.** Connect from 10.21.21.7 to 10.21.23.4 using **Microsoft RDP**, do nothing and **each 2-3 minutes i am getting disconnected from RDP session** and then reconnecting. According to ping data from 10.21.21.7 to 10.23.23.4 there is timeout (for 2-3 ping requests), but at the same time ping from 10.23.23.1 (host) to 10.23.23.4 show that there weren`t any timeouts.

**Configuration :**
`/etc/network/interfaces (backup01)`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address xx.xx.xx.95
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xx.xx.xx.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
    address  10.21.23.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables-restore -n < /root/rules.txt
```

Script which i use to create VLAN-to-VLAN connection

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/tun_serv
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tun_serv
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Tun
# Description:       Tunnel
### END INIT INFO      

tun_name='tun_serv';
localip='xx.xx.xx.95';
remouteip='yy.yy.yy.213';
tunip='172.16.0.2';
ptpip='172.16.0.1';
route_to_net=10.21.21.0/24;

touch /var/lock/$tun_name;

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo "Create $tun_name Network"

        ip tunnel add $tun_name mode ipip local $localip remote $remouteip dev vmbr0
        ifconfig $tun_name $tunip/30 pointopoint $ptpip
        ifconfig $tun_name up

        echo "add routes to $route_to_net !"
        ip route add $route_to_net via $ptpip dev $tun_name metric 0

        echo "Add iptables rulles for multicast on ${tun_name}"

        iptables -A INPUT -s $ptpip/30 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -d $ptpip/30 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j ACCEPT
        ;;
  stop)
        echo "Stopping Network $tun_name"
        ifconfig $tun_name down
        echo "Remove routes"
        ip route del $route_to_net via $ptpip dev $tun_name metric 0

        ;;
  remove)
        echo "Stopping Network $tun_name"
        ifconfig $tun_name down
        echo "Remove Network $tun_name"
        ip tunnel del $tun_name

        echo "Remove routes"
        ip route del $route_to_net via $ptpip dev $tun_name metric 0

        echo "Remove rules from iptables $tun_name"
        iptables -D INPUT -s $ptpip/30 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -D INPUT -d $ptpip/30 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -D INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
        iptables -D INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j ACCEPT
        ;;

  *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$tun_name {start|stop|remove}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```